# Changing the <li> class place when changing page & include the file in different pages

Tags: php, html, navbar, nav

How do I include this: `header.php` file in different pages?

`header.php`:

```
<li>page1</li>
<li class="current" >page2</li>
<li>page3</li>
```

And then change: `<li **class="current"** >page2</li>` to `page1` when I click on a link and change the page.

Page1:

```
<li class="current" >page1</li>
<li>page2</li>
<li>page3</li>
```

Comment: do you use any PHP Templating engine?

Comment: Use `include()` or `require()` or one the variants of those to include the header in a page. For your `current` class you need a way to determine what the current page is and a way to relate that to the list element.

Comment: yes i know , but i search a way to determine what the current ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a variable

```
 // At page1
 $currentPage = 'page1';

 <?php include 'yourHeaderFolder/header.php'; ?>
```

header.php:

```
<li <?php if ($currentPage === 'page1') { echo 'class="current"'; } ?> >page1</li>
<li <?php if ($currentPage === 'page2') { echo 'class="current"'; } ?> >page2</li>
<li <?php if ($currentPage === 'page3') { echo 'class="current"'; } ?> >page3</li>
```

Comment: <nav>
<ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
<li <?php if ($currentPage === 'home') { echo 'class="current-menu-item"'} ?> ><a href="index.html">Acceuil<span class="subheader">Bienvenu</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
when i include this header.php the all include off my page don't work but the first one did sorry i paste one <li> tag because dzmaximum of characters

Comment: echo statement should end with semi-colon(;)